# Difference between obj1 = obj.clone() and obj1= obj

Tags: java, clone

Can someone please explain the difference between `obj1 = obj.clone()` and `obj1 = obj`?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()

Comment: obj1=obj.clone is a clone for obj. duplicates the object. ob1=obj is just a reference for obj as obj1. If you change something in obj it will reflect obj1.the previous one not

Comment: It's not even that. `clone()` is incredibly broken and should rarely ever be used.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, one creates a clone, and the other does not.

```
obj = new Object();

obj1 = obj;               // obj1 and obj reference *the same object*
```

versus

```
obj1 = obj.clone();       // obj1 references *a copy of* obj
```

Answer (score 1):

Cloning (`obj1 = obj.clone()`) means that you create a **new** object that is **equal** to the old one. Simple assignment (`obj1 = obj`) means that you just have another reference **to the same object**.

The best way to illustrate it is to think what happens when you modify the original object.

Consider the following example:

```
Cat orig = new Cat();
Cat assigned = orig;
Cat cloned = orig.clone();

orig.setGrumpy(true);
```

The last line turns the `orig` cat to be grumpy. Now, `assigned` is also grumpy, since it's just another reference to the same object. `cloned`, on the other hand, remains unchanged, since once you clone an object, you lose any memory that it was created from another object.

Answer (score 0):

`obj.clone()` creates a new object - basically a copy of obj. Thus, after calling `obj1 = obj.clone()` you have **two different objects** obj1 and obj. When calling `obj1 = obj` both `obj` and `obj1` will **refer the same object**.

i.e., when calling `obj1 = obj` you have something like this:

```
obj --> *obj* <-- obj1
```

When calling `obj1 = obj.clone()` you have something like this:

```
obj --> *obj*
obj1 --> *copy of obj*
```

Answer (score 0):

The first will make a new copy of the object *if and only if* this object implements `Cloneable`. If it doesn't, `.clone()` will throw [`CloneNotSupportedException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CloneNotSupportedException.html).

The second simply copies the reference.

See [the javadoc for `Cloneable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html)